# Call one of two async functions but not both

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, settimeout

I have a project with the following basic setup... (I stripped it down to just the necessary parts, but there are other functions besides setHtml in the engine object)

```
var engine = {
    setHtml:function(){
        htmlGenerator(callback)
        //if htmlGenerator takes 5 or more seconds to respond, skip the item. 
        //Otherwise, continue with regular flow

        function skip(){
            //skip the current item
        }

        function callback(){
            //continue with regular flow
        }
    }

}
```

It seems simple enough, but there are a few challenges...

htmlGenerator is located in another file. I have no way of knowing whether that function is synchronous or asynchronous, and ideally that doesn't matter.

htmlGenerator will call callback() when it's ready.

Exactly one of either skip() or callback() should be called, not both or none.

If htmlGenerator takes longer than 5s to call callback, I want to call skip(). This does not mean htmlGenerator will not call callback().

skip() may be called recursively, but cannot be determined whether or not it will be called recursively. (i.e. part of the skip call is to call setHtml again with a new set of data, which may or may not result in another call taking 5 or more seconds)

This is a front-end application, so I would like to avoid bringing on additional libraries/modules/packages if possible, as load times are a top priority.

For a while, I had something like the following, but that didn't work for reasons I cannot explain.

```
var engine = {
    skipTimer:null
    setHtml:function(){
        htmlGenerator(callback)
        //if htmlGenerator takes 5 or more seconds to respond, skip the item. 
        //Otherwise, continue with regular flow

        engine.skipTimer = setTimeout(skip,5000)

        function skip(){
            console.log(engine.skipTimer)//this would correctly display the timer's ID.
            //skip the current item
        }

        function callback(){
            console.log(engine.skipTimer)//this was "false" or "null" or something to that effect
            clearTimeout(engine.skipTimer) //for some reason, the timer was never cleared

            //continue with regular flow
        }
    }

}
```

In my test cases, I didn't call the function with multiple failures (skips), however I do need it to handle that.

I also tried the following, with just as little success...

```
var engine = {
    setHtml:function(){
        var called = false;
        htmlGenerator(callback)
        //if htmlGenerator takes 5 or more seconds to respond, skip the item. 
        //Otherwise, continue with regular flow

        engine.skipTimer = setTimeout(skip,5000)

        function skip(){
            if (called)return;
            called = true;
            //skip the current item
        }

        function callback(){
            if(called)return;
            called = true;
            //continue with regular flow
        }
    }

}
```

If you understand why those results failed, or how to solve this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if `htmlGenerator` is syncronous there is not way to stop it by timeout,

Comment: if htmlGenerator is synchronous, then the timer shouldn't matter. I'll always get a value back in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since htmlGenerator may be async or sync, it will be a good idea to use `Promise`. Specifically `Promise.race()`.

```
var engine = {
    setHtml:function(){
        var called = false;
        var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve){
            htmlGenerator(function(){
                resolve(true)
            });
        }
        //if htmlGenerator takes 5 or more seconds to respond, skip the item. 
        //Otherwise, continue with regular flow
        var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve) { 
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(false)
            }, 5000);
        });

        return Promise.race([p1,p2]);
    }

}
```

The above means your engine.setHtml will return a Promise that resolves to `true` if htmlGenerator calls it's call back first, or `false` if the 5 seconds timeout beat it to it.

So the usage would be a bit like this (I'm assuming

```
engine.setHtml().then(function(generated){
    if (generated){
        // Do stuff here for when htmlGenerator "wins" the callback race.
    } else {
        // Generator lost, you want to skip, do whatever things you need to do to "skip".
    }
});
```

Note that if you want to continue within the setHtml function, instead of `return Promise.race([p1,p2])`, do this instead.

```
Promise.race([p1,p2]).then(function(generated){
    if (generated){
        // Do stuff here for when htmlGenerator "wins" the callback race.
    } else {
        // Generator lost, you want to skip, do whatever things you need to do to "skip".
    }
});
```

A little bit of an explanation. The first block of code essentially creates two "Promises" that can resolve individually. Promise `p1` resolves to a value of true (`resolve(true)`) when htmlGenerator calls its callback. Promise `p2` resolves to a value of false (`resolve(false)`) when setTimeout times out (in your case 5 seconds).

The Promise.race will resolve using which ever Promise that resolves first. So if htmlGenerator calls its callback first, the `Promise.race` resolves to the value of `p1`, which is resolved to `true`. Conversely, if setTimeout calls its callback first, `Promise.race` resolves to the value of `p2`, which is resolved to `false`. Finally, when you use `Promise.race([p1,p2]).then(callback)` the callback receives the resolved value of `Promise.race([p1,p2])`, which will be the resolved value of the promise [p1,p2] that won the race..

Comment: Unfortunately, due to needing to support older browsers, I cannot use Promises. (Thanks, IE8/9) However I'll certainly look into this when we make the decision to drop support for older browsers.

Comment: Oh... nuts. However, if you're willing to use a polyfill, here's one that adds Promise functionality to IE8+ https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise (disclaimer, not associated with that library in anyway).

Comment: Interesting. If I can't solve this without using promises, I'll look into that package. Thanks.

Comment: Despite not being able to use promises, I feel like this is the 'correct' response to this, so I'll mark this as my accepted answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe will occur when `htmlGenerator()` is processed synchronously. In this case the `htmlGenerator`, and therefore `callback()`, will be executed *before* the `setTimeout` is called, so you call `clearTimeout` on `null`. This means no timer is cleared. You then start the timer as soon as `htmlGenerator` completes, hence `skip` is always called.

To fix this you simply need to set the timer *before* you call `htmlGenerator`:

```
var engine = {
    skipTimer:null
    setHtml:function() {
        engine.skipTimer = setTimeout(skip, 5000);
        htmlGenerator(callback);

        function skip() {
            console.log(engine.skipTimer)
        }

        function callback(){
            console.log(engine.skipTimer);
            clearTimeout(engine.skipTimer);
        }
    }
}
```

To get a clear view of the difference check the console in [**this working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sh6z456d/), which only shows the timer id from the `callback()` function, against [**your original version**](https://jsfiddle.net/qr47dgs1/) where you first see `null` from callback, then the timer id from `skip()`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that for synchronous calls. Unfortunately, this only solves the problem halfway. If Callback is called, skip does not get called (which is good). However, if skip gets called, this doesn't stop Callback from being called, which in my case is very important. How can I get Skip to stop Callback from being called?

Comment: Perhaps have `skip()` set a variable (like `skipped` in your original example).  Then, wrap your callback in another function that check if `skipped` is still false before executing the callback. If skipped is true, skip the callback.

Comment: Ok, so by using part of my solution earlier (using the 'called' variable) i was able to stop Callback from being called if Skip was called. looks something like this...
   var engine = {
    setHtml:function(){
        var called = false;
        htmlGenerator(callback)

        function skip(){
            called=true;
            //skip current item
        }

        function callback(){
            if (called) return;
            //continue with regular flow
        }
    }

}